# При JsonSerializer.Deserialize поле становиться null

Tags: c#

Сериализую данный класс

```
public class Test
    {
        public Test(string name, ObservableCollection<Question> questions)
        {
            Name = name;
            Questions = questions;
            createTestDate = DateTime.Now;            
        }

        public Test()
        {
            createTestDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Question>();

        private int timerValue;
        public int TimerValue
        {
            get => timerValue;
            private set => timerValue = value;
        }

        private DateTime createTestDate;
        public DateTime CreateTestDate
        {
            get => createTestDate;
            private set => createTestDate = value;
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set => name = value;
        }

        private string pathFile;
        public string PathFile
        {
            get => pathFile;
            set => pathFile = value;
        }
    }
```

Класс Question внутри коллекции Questions

```
public class Question : ObservableCollection<IItem>
    {
        private string questionName;        
        public string QuestionName
        {
            get => questionName;
            set => questionName = value;
        }

        public Question(IEnumerable<IItem> items) : base(items) { }

        public Question() { }          
    }
```

Поле QuestionName после десериализации становиться null.

Класс отвечающий за десериализацию и сериализацию

```
public interface IFileService
    {
        Test Open(string filename);
        void Save(Test test);
        void DeleteFile(string path);
        IEnumerable<Test> OpenFileDirectory(string folderPath,string fileExtension);
    }

    public class JsonFormatterService : IFileService
    {
        public void DeleteFile(string path)
        {
             File.Delete(path);
        }

        public Test Open(string filename)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
               return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(fs);
            }
        }

        async public void Save(Test test)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(test.PathFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(fs, test);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Test> OpenFileDirectory(string folderPath, string fileExtension)
        {
            List<Test> result = new List<Test>();
            var filesPath = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, fileExtension);
            foreach (var file in filesPath)
            {
                result.Add(Open(file));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Очень много лишнего, того, что вообще не относится к вопросу) [Вот все](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WAnmfZ), что нужно для вопроса, как видите, всего один класс и методы сериализации/десериализации. Ну а что касается проблемы, она заключается в том, что вы непойми зачем наследуетесь от коллекции, то есть ваш `Question` - это коллекция, которая и должна сериализироваться как коллекция, а именно `[ объект1, объект2, ...]`, все остальные данные (например размер) не важен для хранимых данных. Ну а вы туда запихнули еще и имя, которое как по вашему должно отображаться?

Comment: Единственный вариант у вас в данном случае - писать свой конвертор, который будет именно вашу коллекцию преобразовывать в нужный вид, например `"имя" : [1, 2, 3, ...]`, но в таком случае, зачем вам тогда наследование, когда можно (и нужно) делать нормальный класс, который будет содержать в себе нужные данные + коллекцию чего-то..? Короче, вы сейчас сами себе палки в колеса запихиваете, и я вот не пойму зачем)

Comment: Я вывожу этот класс в CollectionView с параметром IsGrouped="True", если я в классе Question просто напишу коллекцию ObservableCollection<IItem> то я не смогу  выводить ее в CollectionView с параметром IsGrouped="True", или это как-то можно сделать?

Comment: Почему у вас вообще "Вопрос" - это "Коллекция"? Вот у вас есть пачка бумаги, один лист - это коллекция? Нет, это один "объект", с определенными свойствами, а вот "Пачка бумаги" - да, это уже коллекция, которая содержит в себе листы. Также и тут, у вас **один** вопрос, почему он вдруг коллекция, я не пойму... Если вопрос состоит к примеру из вариантов ответа, то это должен быть также один класс, но который уже в себе будет содержать доп. свойство с типом коллекции, но сам он от этого не становиться коллекцией.

Comment: Я только начал изучать maui и я руководствовался данной статьёй: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping?view=net-maui-8.0, можно ли использовать группировку при выводе данных не наследуясь от коллекции?

Comment: Без понятия, я не MAUI разработчик (мне он не понравился). В WPF к примеру это делается без подобной "коллекции обертки", примерно [так](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-and-sorting-in-listbox-in-wpf/), где создается `ICollectionView`, которой задается группа по конкретному свойству (задается просто имя). Может в MAUI есть аналог, не знаю, ищите. Вообще, за хранение и за привязку должны отвечать разные классы, разные "слои", где за хранение должен отвечать Model слой и простые DTO классы, без какой либо логики. Так что, может вам перед сохранением избавляться от групп?

Comment: Думаю всё-таки привидеться избавиться от групп, вероятно этот подход плох при сериализации что я не учёл.